# Saving an E-Mail after downloading with JavaMail

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I'm building an E-Mail Application, so I want to save the E-Mails to the Device, my App is running on.

I know that there is the function MimeMessage.writeTo(), but I've problems with handling MimeMessages through my Application so I made my own class, called Mail!

How can I save an Object (or Object-Array) of this class on my Phone?
Should it be an XML-File?!

I looked for this in the Internet but the only I said it the function I mentioned before!

Thanks :)

Comment: If you've designed your own object it's pretty much up to you to figure out how to save it.  Is it Serializable?  What problems did you have with MimeMessage?

Comment: MimeMessage problems: Couldn't pass a MimeMessage via a Bundle to another activity and MimeMessage-Content has to be converted to HTML/Plain Text...

Comment: Is it possible to serialise my Object with Googles Gson?

Comment: I suspect that depends on the design of your object.  You can always use MimeMessage.writeTo to write the message into a ByteArrayOutputStream then extract the byte array and pass it around.  You can reconstruct a MimeMessage object using the constructor that takes an InputStream (by using a [SharedByteArrayInputStream](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/util/SharedByteArrayInputStream.html)) but you'll need to provide a new Session and of course the message will lose all association with the Folder and Store it came from.

Comment: It worked for me with GSON and my own class. The only thing I don't have tested right know, is how to save the Attachment!