# How can I save downloaded emails using Javamail in Android

Tags: java, android, jakarta-mail

I build an Email application android now, so I want to save the E-Mails to the Device, Someone told eml file and serialize your own class! Can anyone will guide me in true direction please help me! And How can I load quickly all mailboxes using `onScrollListner()` method because now it very slow

I've using asynctask to load this! This is my code:

```
private class CheckMailInboxTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Message[]>{
    private int count;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private Message[] messages;
    private boolean statusMail = true;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog.setTitle("Loading mail");
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progressDialog.show();
    }
    @Override
    protected Message[] doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        try {
            messages = AccueilActivity.emailManager.getMails();
            EmailManager.inbox.addMessageCountListener(new MessageCountAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void messagesAdded(MessageCountEvent e) {
                    super.messagesAdded(e);
                    System.out.println("New Message");
                    try {
                        Message[] messages = e.getMessages();
                        int count = messages.length;
                        for(int i=(count - 1);i >= 0;i--){
                            final MimeMessage msg = (MimeMessage) messages[i];
                            Mail email = null;
                            try {
                                email = new Mail(msg);
                                email.set_box(true);
                                Mail.INBOX.add(0,email);
                                Mail.LISTBOOL.add(Boolean.valueOf(true));//Nampiako
                                if(BoiteReceptionActivity.handler != null){
                                    BoiteReceptionActivity.handler.sendEmptyMessage(1);
                                    ab.setSubtitle("1 mail non lu(s)");
                                }
                            } catch (IOException ex) {
                                ex.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (MessagingException emx) {
                    }
                }
            });
            new Thread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    System.out.println("UUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUUU");
                    if (EmailManager.inbox instanceof IMAPFolder) {
                        final IMAPFolder imapFolder = (IMAPFolder)EmailManager.inbox;
                        startListening(imapFolder);
                    }
                    System.out.println("DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD");
                }
            }).start();

            count = messages.length;
            for(int i=(count - 1);i >= 0;i--){
                MimeMessage msg = (MimeMessage) messages[i];
                Mail email = null;
                try {
                    if(msg.isSet(Flags.Flag.SEEN)){
                        email = new Mail(msg);
                        email.set_box(true);
                        Mail.INBOX.add(email);
                        Mail.LISTBOOL.add(Boolean.valueOf(false));
                        Log.d("SIZE OF MAIL_INBOX SEEN", ""+Mail.INBOX.size());
                        Log.d("SIZE OF BOOL SEEN", ""+Mail.LISTBOOL.get(0));

                    }else {
                        email = new Mail(msg);
                        email.set_box(true);
                        Mail.INBOX.add(email);
                        Mail.LISTBOOL.add(Boolean.valueOf(true));
                        Log.d("SIZE OF MAIL_INBOX RECENT", ""+Mail.INBOX.size());
                        Log.d("SIZE OF BOOL RECENT", ""+Mail.LISTBOOL.size());

                    }
                    AccueilActivity.emailManager.setInboxList(Mail.INBOX);
                    new Thread(new Runnable() {      
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            BoiteReceptionActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    //Mail.COUNT_MESSAGES = Mail.INBOX.size();
                                    Mail.in_adapteur.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }).start();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
        }
        return messages;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Message[] messages) {
        super.onPostExecute(messages);

    }
}
```

**EDIT**
And this is my custome adapter

```
public class AdapterBoiteReception extends BaseAdapter{
   private Context context;
   private List<Mail> listMail;
   private List<Boolean> listBool;

   public AdapterBoiteReception(Context ctx, List<Mail> list, List<Boolean> listBool){
      this.context = ctx;
      this.listMail = list;
      this.listBool = listBool;
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return listMail.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return listMail.get(position);
 }

 @Override
 public long getItemId(int position) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     return listMail.indexOf(getItem(position));
 }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     View view =convertView;
        Holder mailHolder = null;
        LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(view == null){
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.boite_reception_items, null);
            mailHolder = new Holder();

            mailHolder.nomTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.nomMsgTV);
            mailHolder.objetTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.objectMsgTV);
            mailHolder.dateTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.dateMsgTV);
            mailHolder.img = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imgBtnAttache);

            view.setTag(mailHolder);
        }else
            mailHolder = (Holder) view.getTag();
        Mail mail = listMail.get(position);
        Log.d("VALUE OF LISTBOOL", ""+Boolean.valueOf(listBool.get(position)));
        if(Boolean.valueOf(listBool.get(position)).equals(Boolean.TRUE)){
            mailHolder.nomTV.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            mailHolder.objetTV.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
            mailHolder.dateTV.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);

            mailHolder.nomTV.setText(mail.getNom());
            mailHolder.objetTV.setText(mail.getSubject());
            try {
                mailHolder.dateTV.setText(mail.getDate());
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(mail.getHandlers().size() > 0)
                mailHolder.img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                mailHolder.img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        }else{
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
            mailHolder.nomTV.setText(mail.getNom());
            mailHolder.objetTV.setText(mail.getSubject());
            try {
                mailHolder.dateTV.setText(mail.getDate());
            } catch (MessagingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if(mail.getHandlers().size() > 0)
                mailHolder.img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else
                mailHolder.img.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

    return view;

}
static class Holder{
    TextView nomTV;
    TextView objetTV;
    TextView dateTV;
    ImageButton img;
}
```

}

**EDIT**

@the_dani had the same of mine problem too [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781023/saving-an-e-mail-after-downloading-with-javamail)

Comment: Mail is my own class and this asynctask is inside my Activity that show the list of email

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Message.writeTo](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/Part.html#writeTo-java.io.OutputStream-) method to save a copy of a message, e.g., to a FileOutputStream.  (A Message is a Part, and Part defines the writeTo method.)

Comment: Thanks  for your answer!Each message will have its file??Or it's possible to combine all copies of Message[] in one file?

Comment: That's pretty much up to you.  You can run your own mail server locally if you really want to.  You might find the [JavaMail mbox Store](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/MboxStore) helpful.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this!!! May be you have some example to use this mbox in android please

Comment: No, sorry, I don't use Android.

Comment: But it's possible to do this in android email app?

Comment: I don't know.  As I said, I don't use Android.  Maybe we should back up and ask why it is you want to store email messages locally on your Android device?  What are you going to do with them when they're stored?

Comment: Thanks for your reply.You asked me that "why it is you want to store email messages locally on your Android device?"My application loads from the server the emails every time I open my INBOX for example. So that's why I want to save the mail in android device so I can see after although I have not connexion.Like the gmail app for example, how they did?

Comment: It sounds like you want a local cache of messages that will be kept in sync with the remote mailbox.  You've got a lot of work ahead of you!  You'll want to become intimately familiar with IMAP UIDs.  Storing your local cache of messages in an mbox Store might help, depending on how you decide to manage all the data for your cache.

Comment: Thanks again for your answer!of corse that's what I wanted to do! some ideas about mboxe Store please?

Comment: What kind of ideas are you looking for?  I recommend reading the page I linked to above and trying it on your desktop to see if it does what you want before even trying it on Android.

Comment: Thanks I've already read this!My question is what can I synchronize mbox store with remote  server(IMAP or POP3)?

Comment: With great difficulty.  That question requires an extremely long answer, which you're going to have to discover for yourself by doing a lot of reading.

Comment: Thanks so I'll do that!thanks again for your suggestions @Bill Shannon!